# Gridview sorting - fetching data sorted by arbitrary sort expression from Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linq, rest, webforms, asp.net-4.5

I have an ASP.NET 4.5 webforms application based on a set of ASP.NET WebAPI REST services that provide the data to the pages, and I'm using the strongly-typed data controls and webforms databinding to simplify my code.

On my ASPX page, I'd like to show a grid and allow the user to sort the data presented by clicking on the column headers. I'm having trouble getting the sorting to work. The ASPX side works fine - I added a `string sortExpression` parameter to my `GetMethod` and it gets populated correctly (with `Title` or `Title DESC` if I click on the `Title` column), with the configuration sort expressions as defined per column.

```
public List<MyBasicDto> GetData(string sortByExpression, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows, out int totalRowCount)
{
    return _client.GetMyData(sortByExpression, startRowIndex, maximumRows, out totalRowCount);
}
```

However, on the server-side (in my ASP.NET WebAPI REST service), I'm having trouble getting the data from my database table using EF 6.1.3.

```
public List<MyBasicDto> GetBasicDto(string sortby, int startrow, int maxrows)
{
    try
    {
        int skip = startrow > 0 ? startrow - 1 : 0;

        string sortExpression = sortby ?? "DateEntered DESC";

        List<MyEntity> entities = _dbContext.MyEntity.OrderBy(sortExpression).Skip(skip).Take(maxrows).ToList();

        List<MyBasicDto> results = Mapper.Map<List<MyEntity>, List<MyBasicDto>>(entities);
        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        Log.Fatal("GetBasicDto - Exception", exc);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The trouble occurs at compile time, when I get this compiler error:

> The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Queryable.OrderBy(System.Linq.IQueryable, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

??? All the examples I find online seem to work just like this - provide the sort expression as a string, to the `.OrderBy()` Linq method - what is wrong in my code? What exactly does that error mean (sounds rather cryptic to me)?

Comment: Are you using _Dynamic LINQ_?

Comment: @RahulSingh: I'm using just the .NET standard stuff for now. The samples I saw never seemed to mention that they needed anything but the standard LINQ capabilities

Comment: Nope I don't think so standard .Net OrderBy extension method will accept `string` it expects a delegate. Please check this [Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library)

Comment: @RahulSingh: ok, thanks a heap - installing the `System.Linq.Dynamic` NuGet package made all the difference - works like a charm now! If you formulate this as an answer, I'll be more than happy to accept it (as soon as the site here let's me do so)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, *System.LINQ* [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) method expects a delegate and not a string thus the error.

You will have to use *Dynamic Linq* as demonstrated in [ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library).